# Azure Application Insights does not show C# ILogger logs

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

We're trying to get Application Insights enabled for our ASP Net Core 7.0 C# application.  We've used a few sources, including this Microsoft site:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001942&tabs=dotnet6

The Azure Application Insights module itself seem correctly configured, for example it's showing app requests correctly.

However our custom ILogger messages in our C# application don't show up in the Azure App Insights `traces` section.

We've based our setup below from various other examples on how to configure ILogging, so we're not sure which aspect of our setup is wrong, but suspect it's in our code somewhere.

### C# Program

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        ...
        
        builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

        builder.Logging.AddApplicationInsights(
            configureTelemetryConfiguration: config =>
                 config.ConnectionString = configuration["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"],
            configureApplicationInsightsLoggerOptions: options => { }
        );
        
        ... 

        var app = builder.Build();
    }
```

### appsettings.json

```json
Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
      "ApplicationInsights": "Debug"
    }
  }
```

### csproj file

```
  <ItemGroup>
    ...
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.21.0" />
    ...
  </ItemGroup>
```

### Azure Web App Settings Configuration

[image]

Comment: Yes, the config is wrong, take a look at the right way by examining the configuration in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68353327/ilogger-logging-doesnt-show-up-in-azure-application-insights?rq=2)

Comment: What is the .NET Core version you are using ?

Comment: @PeterBons, you're right about that configuration - do you want to add this as an answer?

Comment: @Harshitha, it's .NET Core 7.0.

Comment: @ArtieLeech - I can see the traces with the below configuration in .NET Core 7 as well.

Comment: This is a very common issue which [trips up many](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75995535/314291) - the additional logging config was a bad design choice IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anything in the config below that looks incorrect?

Yes, the config is wrong, take a look at the right way by examining the following configuration:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see the ApplicationInsights loglevel is set in a subsection.

Comment: Once we applied the changes as described here by Peter, our C# application ILogger 
logs started to show in Application Insights.   Note that the ApplicationInsights config element is directly below the root Logging element, NOT within the LogLevel element.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Peter Bons for the comment.

Yes, as mentioned by Peter Bons, your configuration file is not having all the required settings.

If you are running `ASP Net Core C# application` locally, then we need to set the Application Insights `Connection String/Instrumentation Key` in the `appsettings.json` file.

***My `.csproj` file:***

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>     
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.21.0" />        
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

***My `appsettings.json` file:***

```cs
{
  "Logging": {
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "Microsoft": "Error"
      }
    },
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=**********;IngestionEndpoint=https://****.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://****.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"
  }
}
```

***My `Program.cs` file:***

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

//var abc = builder.Configuration["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"];

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

***My `Controller.cs`:***

```cs
 private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("Test Warning trace - June 5");
            _logger.LogError("Test Error - June 5");

            return View();
        }
```

***Application Insights Transaction Search:***

[image]

You can see I am able to log Exceptions as well.