# What is causing missing Azure App Insights trace logs on non-development environment?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-application-insights, appinsights

I have configured App Insights on a .NET 6 project that is in production currently, with the code explained below. However, on a development environment hosted on an App Service, I can see a full list of trace logs for a queue worker (service), and for the same service on production, only Error (severity 3) traces appear.

What could be causing such a symptom? Is there some implicit environment handling code to prevent traces appearing on a non-development environment?

As shown below, I do have a QueueTelemetryFilter class which filters for non-success telemetry over a certain time period, but this a) affects telemetry, and b) would be consistent across all environments if it was the cause.

**Configuration:**

Program.cs

```cs
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor<QueueTelemetryFilter>();
```

appsettings.Development.json / appsettings.Production.json

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "[REDACTED]"
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

```cs
public class SomeQueueProcessor: ISomeQueueProcessor
{
    private readonly ILogger<SomeQueueProcessor> logger;

    public SomeQueueProcessor(
        ILogger<SomeQueueProcessor> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task HandleQueue(SomeMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        logger.LogInformation("Begin SomeTask", message.Metadata);

        // some code 

        try {
            // some more code
        catch(SomeException se){
            logger.LogError("SomeTask Failed", se.ExceptionMetadata);
        }

        logger.LogInformation("End SomeTask", message.Metadata);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the `data sampling` setting of the `App Insights` resource in your Production env,..that may be set to anything less than 100%.

Comment: Try with this [configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76403858/19648279) and check once.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out - we had an incorrectly configured environment, which was registering a duplicate App Insights logger in Serilog.

Since, we've removed any logging for App Insights in Serilog, and just integrate with App Insights directly.